# Javascript reduction loop doesnt work

Tags: javascript

OK its late so I must be doing something stupid, but myreduction for loop which works fine in c# does not work in javascript. The loop is NEVER entered. What have I missed?

```
var count = 12;
var j = count - 3
    for (i = count; i<1 ; i--)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            break;
        else
            j = i - 1;
    }

alert(j);
```

In this case I am expecting the following:

```
12 -> 9;
11 -> 7;
10 -> 7;
9 -> 6;
8 -> 4;
7 -> 4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = count; i>1 ; i--)
```

??

You want the loop to continue while i is greater than 1 (perhaps this might differ with this logic change)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
for (var i = count; i > 1 ; i--) {
   // code
}
```